# Local Settings in Django 2

Tags: django, django-settings

I'm using Django 2 with Python 3.7

I want to import some settings from a file local_settings.py so I can include that file in a .gitignore so I don't share my secret keys on github.

I have the folder tree set up like this:
[image: folder tree]

settings.py has this at the end:

```
try:
       from local_settings import *
    except ImportError:
        pass

    ORDERS = '@catsinuniform.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json'

    PRODUCTS = '@catsinuniform.myshopify.com/admin/products.json'

    SHOPIFY_SECRET_KEY = ''

    SHOPIFY_PWORD = ''

    ORDERS_URL = f"https://{SHOPIFY_SECRET_KEY}:{SHOPIFY_PWORD}{ORDERS}"

    PRODUCTS_URL = f"https://{SHOPIFY_SECRET_KEY}:{SHOPIFY_PWORD}{PRODUCTS}"
```

I would also like to put my SECRET_KEY in local_settings.py

This isn't working and I can't find why not? Is it my Python version or Django?

Comment: What do you mean, "isn't working"? What exactly did you try, and what happens? (Note the point of that local_settings pattern is that the import goes at the very end of the file, otherwise you won't be able to overwrite any of the subsequent settings. But this doesn't affect your SECRET_KEY anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Because your `local_settings.py` is getting imported first, then overrriden by your settings. IF you want to use this pattern, do your import at the end of the file.

A better way would be to strore your secret keys in an environment variable set on the server which is then imported into your settings file using something like:

`SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', 'some_sort_of_sane_default_for_your_dev')`

Comment: ORDERS_URL and PRODUCTS_URL are still blank so I'm getting a key error when I import the urls into  my views?

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to  import it from your `__init__.py` file

```
from .settings import *
try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError as exc:
    exc.args = tuple(
        ['%s (local_settings.py missing)' % exc.args[0]])
raise exc
```